# hive: create table / data type syntax for comma separated files

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

The text file is comma separated. However, one of the columns ex: "Issue" with value "Other (phone, health club, etc)" also contains commas.

**Question:** What should the data type of "Issue" be? And how should I format the table (row format delimited terminated by) so that the comma in the column (issue) is accounted for correctly

I had set it this way:

```
create table consumercomplaints (ComplaintID int,
                                  Product string,
                                  Subproduct string,
                                  Issue string,
                                  Subissue string,
                                  State string,
                                  ZIPcode int,
                                  Submittedvia string,
                                  Datereceived string,
                                  Datesenttocompany string,
                                  Company string,
                                  Companyresponse string,
                                  Timelyresponse string,
                                  Consumerdisputed string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
location '/user/hive/warehouse/mydb/consumer_complaints.csv';
```

Sample data --
Complaint ID,Product,Sub-product,Issue,Sub-issue,State,ZIP code,Submitted via,Date received,Date sent to company,Company,Company response,Timely response?,Consumer disputed?
943291,Debt collection,,Cont'd attempts collect debt not owed,Debt is not mine,MO,63123,Web,07/18/2014,07/18/2014,"Enhanced Recovery Company, LLC",Closed with non-monetary relief,Yes,
943698,Bank account or service,Checking account,Deposits and withdrawals,,CA,93030,Web,07/18/2014,07/18/2014,U.S. Bancorp,In progress,Yes,
943521,Debt collection,,Cont'd attempts collect debt not owed,Debt is not mine,OH,44116,Web,07/18/2014,07/18/2014,"Vital Solutions, Inc.",Closed with explanation,Yes,
943400,Debt collection,"Other (phone, health club, etc.)",Communication tactics,Frequent or repeated calls,MD,21133,Web,07/18/2014,07/18/2014,"The CBE Group, Inc.",Closed with explanation,Yes,

Comment: Are values in the `Issue` column enclosed by `"`s when they contain a `,`?

Comment: nope. they are plain text

Comment: I don't see how that can possibly be parsed correctly.  Can you post an example row from the CSV?  Doesn't have to be real data, just an equivalent fake row.

Comment: I am sorry, the values in the Issue column are enclosed by "s. Please see the question details for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to format your output data by some control character like Control-A. I don't think there will be any data type to support this. OR you can write a UDF to load the data and take care of formatting in the UDF logic.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing a serde, you could do 2 things,

1. escape the comma in the original data before loading, using some character. for e.g. `\`
   and then use the hive `create table` command using `row format delimited fields terminated by ',' escaped by **'\'**`
2. you can use a regex that takes care of the comma enclosed within double quotes,
   so first you apply a regex to data as shown in hortonworks/apache manuals,
   `regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?){1}', 1) player_id`  source:https://web.archive.org/web/20171125014202/https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-hive/
   Ensure that you are able to load and see your data using this expression ( barring the enclosed commas).
   Then modify the expression to account for enclosed commas. You can do something like this,

   `String s = "a,\"hi, I am here\",c,d,\"ahoy, mateys\"";
   String pattern ="^(?:([^\",]*|\"[^\"]*\"),?){4}";
   p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
   if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("YES-"+m.groupCount());
       System.out.println("=>"+m.group(1));
   }`

   by changing {4} to {1}, {2}, ... you can get respective fields.